# Tela de Login Php Não Autentica

Tags: php

Estou iniciando na programação com PHP, Sendo que Minha tela de Login Não ta Recebendo o  Usuario e senha, esse e o código da minha pagina de Verificação, vocês pode ver o que tem de errado por favor.

```
<?php
include('conexao.php');
if (empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])){
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']);

$query = "SELECT * from cad.usuario where usuario = '{$usuario}' and senha = '{$senha}'";

$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($row > 0){
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header('Location: principal.php');
    exit();
}else{
    $_SESSION['não_autenticado'] = true;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Qual o erro que está acontecendo? Entra no primeiro if?

Comment: o erro é que ele Não loga, quando informo o usuario e senha que ta registrado no Banco de Dados, ele volta para tela de login e Fica assim, Já Limpei o cache do navegado mais Não sai da tela de index

Comment: Falta o session_start, sessões só funcionam com session_start

Comment: Caso esteja entrando no primeiro `if (empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])){` os dados podem estar chegando via get `$_GET` por esquecimento da definição do atributo method="post" na tag `<form>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falta o session_start, sessões só funcionam com session_start, assim:

```
<?php
include('conexao.php');
if (empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])){
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']);

$query = "SELECT * from cad.usuario where usuario = '{$usuario}' and senha = '{$senha}'";

$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

session_start();

if($row > 0){
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header('Location: principal.php');
    exit();
}else{
    $_SESSION['não_autenticado'] = true;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

Todas páginas que precisam estar "logadas", após o login é claro, terão que ter session_start no começo, algo como:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Comment: Tente aqui mais mesmo assim Não loga com o usuario que tenho no banco Não sei oq eu fazer mais

Comment: @LUIZAUGUSTOSURF o que `var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($result));` retorna? PROVAVELMENTE  o erro é nas suas outras paginas que também não usam session_start, session_start tem que estar em todas paginas que precisam do login

Comment: Quero agradeçe a todos vocês pela dicas e por mim ajuda consegui Muito Obrigado mesmo Deu Certo Aqui Muito obrigado mesmo a todos que teverão um tempinho par amim ajuda

Comment: @LUIZAUGUSTOSURF foi o session_start que faltava? Se sim marque a resposta como correta por favor ... se não formule uma resposta de como resolveu para ajudar futuros visitantes

Comment: Sim foi sim a Session_start que tava flatando em alguma pagina Muito obrigado